# GPT and MBR with Recovery Partition

Tags: mbr, gpt, recovery-partition

I purchased a laptop with GPT partition table. On the hard drive I have one partition-recovery partition and the other is the OS partition.

Since it is Windows 8.1, I need to install 7 Pro. I want to change the GPT to MBR format table. I have the instruction to convert but I need to know if this won't affect/delete my recovery partition (my recovery partition is Win 8.1 Home). Will the conversion delete the recovery partition?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to switch partition types?

Comment: You may want to consider creating recovery disks first..so that if you plan to restore windows 8.1 you can do so using the recovery disks even if the recovery partition is later lost.   If you have Windows 7 64bit, you need not change GPT to MBR. Windows 7 64 bit supports install and boot off GPT disk. Disable Secure Boot feature as it is not supported by Win 7 before installing.

Comment: Thanks pat2015, my queries is, will the conversion deletes the recovery partition ?. Note that One physical drive with 2 partition, : one is recovery and the other is OS. the disk is a GPT type. (I only want to convert the OS partition which i first have to delete the previous OS in it )

Answer (score 1):

GPT to MBR conversion is at a Disk level and not Partition level. You convert the whole disk between GPT <=> MBR.

Not sure what instructions you already have. You may want to share the same for further clarity.

If you follow DISKPART command line tool available in Windows  you first need to CLEAN the disk before GPT to MBR conversion can be done and this step clears all partitions from the disk. You may need to invoke the tool from the setup disk / repair options as it may not perform disk conversion on the same disk on which windows is installed and running.

There might be third party tools that claim to convert the disk without deleting partitions but I personally have no experience with them.

Comment: Thanks for all comments. really appreciate. I have never tried if there is any third party software that does conversion on disk without deleting partition as well. will be great to know.

Answer (score 0):

To make your drive GDP  you do not need to convert anything. Simply boot into the Windows 7 Setup and when you click next it is going to give you an error message saying "this drive is MBR not GDP", simply click on the partitions and click delete on all of them. Once all of them are delete, click next and Windows 7 would automatically make a GDP partition.

THIS WILL DELETE EVERYTHING ON THE DRIVE

Answer (score 0):

I have to question why you want to convert from MBR to GPT. Windows 7 is perfectly able to install to a GPT disk in EFI/UEFI mode. Doing so will enable you to keep your Windows 8.1 installation (if you want) and your recovery partition. I've not read it thoroughly, but [this page](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/186875-uefi-unified-extensible-firmware-interface-install-windows-7-a.html) has instructions on performing an EFI-mode installation of Windows 7. Doing a Web search will turn up more such pages.

Comment: to convert gpt to mbr

Comment: I reversed "MBR" and "GPT" in my answer, but my answer still applies: You can install Windows 7 in EFI mode to a GPT disk, so converting from GPT to MBR is likely to be the harder path to a solution, assuming "solution" is simply a computer that successfully boots Windows 7. If you've got a specific reason for favoring MBR or BIOS-mode booting over GPT or EFI-mode booting, then please elaborate.